# I can not add an object from the web application but however it works fine with postman

Tags: java, angular, rest, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to add "a group", I'm using a rest service. I can't understand why I'm getting a http 400 error while the same service works fine with Postman.

here's my code in JEE

Groupe.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groupes")
public class Groupe implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idgrp;



    @NotNull
   // @Lob
    private String nom_groupe;


    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private EntityType entityType;

    public Long getIdgrp() {
        return idgrp;
    }

    public void setIdgrp(Long idgrp) {
        this.idgrp = idgrp;
    }

    public String getNom_groupe() {
        return nom_groupe;
    }

    public void setNom_groupe(String nom_groupe) {
        this.nom_groupe = nom_groupe;
    }

    public EntityType getEntityType() {
        return entityType;
    }

    public void setEntityType(EntityType entityType) {
        this.entityType = entityType;
    }



}
```

My RestService

```
  @PostMapping("/entityTypes/{id_type}/groups")
    public Groupe createGroupe(@PathVariable (value = "id_type") Long id_type,
                                 @Valid @RequestBody Groupe groupe) {
        return entityTypeRepository.findById(id_type).map(entityType -> {
            groupe.setEntityType(entityType);
            return groupeRepository.save(groupe);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("id_type " + id_type + " not found", null, groupe));
    }
```

For now I'm not having any problem, when I try to add a group using Postman it works just fine. My problem is when I use Angular

```
 onSubmit() {
this.grpInfo = new GroupeInfo(
      this.form.nom_groupe
    );
   headers.append('Authorization', window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
    this.http
      .post<any>('http://localhost:8080/entityTypes/' + this.route.snapshot.params['id'] + '/groups', { headers })
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
         // console.log(response.content);
          response.content.nom_groupe = this.grpInfo.nom_groupe;
          //console.log(response);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
 }
```

This is when I get a http 400 error and this error in the backend

```
[nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [1] in public com.hraccess.openhr.myEntities.Groupe com.hraccess.openhr.myController.GroupeController.createGroupe(java.lang.Long,com.hraccess.openhr.myEntities.Groupe): [Field error in object 'groupe' on field 'nom_groupe': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.groupe.nom_groupe,NotNull.nom_groupe,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [groupe.nom_groupe,nom_groupe]; arguments []; default message [nom_groupe]]; default message [ne peut pas être nul]] ]
```

Comment: You're sending (empty) headers as the body of your request. Tip: open your browser dev tools, click on the network tab, and look at what you're sending in your request.

Comment: @JBNizet no , they're not empty   `let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Authorization', window.localStorage.getItem('token'));`

Comment: Your call to append() is useless, that's for sure. But anyway, that's not the main point. The main point is that you're sending the headers as the body of your request.

Comment: no, i'm not , when I replace the "post" with "get" it works  , so i don't think so

Comment: GET request don't have a body. Post requests have one.

Comment: So, what am I supposed to do ? What do I change ? this is why I posted the question

Comment: You need to send a body with your request. The Groupe object that your backend expects as the body of the request: you need to send it. The signature of post() is post(url, body, options). You're using it as if it was post(url, options).

Comment: okay I did this ` .post<any>('http://localhost:8080/entityTypes/' + this.route.snapshot.params['id'] + '/groups',body, { headers })`  with the body ` let body = this.grpInfo.nom_groupe`  and I'm getting 2 different errors a http 415 and another error in the back

Comment: Your backend doesn't expect a String as request body. It expects an **object**, of type Groupe. So you need to snd a JSON object that matches with the structure and JSON mapping defined in the Groupe class.